# Where should I put selector code?

Tags: android, directory, drawable

Where should you put selector code, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="false">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="true">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="false">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="true">
</item>
</selector>
```

Should I create new file in all drawable forlders and paste this code or should I just paste it in values folder? What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the xml in the `drawable` folder `res/drawable/myselector.xml`. Then you can use it as `@drawable/myselector`. No need to create file in all drawable folders.

Comment: But there is no drawable folder.
There is drawable-hdpi xxhdpi mdpi xhdpi folders, no "drawable".
Should I create one?

Comment: @user3178137 can you not create a folder called `drawable` under `res`?. Create one add it there. Nothing to worry

Comment: I was afraid that it could mess up something. Thanks

Comment: @user3178137 nothing to worry. Just put in drawable folder and reference the same.